# Terminate Air Navigator Views

Tags: flex4, air, flash-builder

i'm playing around with the navigator class and custom views within air for android and the Flex HERO SDK

my problem is that it seems like there is no way how to terminate a view.
i start a view using navigator.pushview(myView).

then, when using the return button, i want to CLOSE that view and return back to the main menu.
therefore i'm listening for the onKeyDown Keyboard.BACK event using event.preventDefault() to prevent the application from running the default "go back" action and the navigator.pushview(myOtherView) to go back to main menu.

BUT the problem is that the myView view still seems to be running in the background.

now i'm looking for a way to terminate that myView and everything that is running within in (atm, if i access the cam, the cam is still active even if the view is not active anymore)

can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the navigator data-provider functions like ArrayCollection you could do something like `navigator.removeItemAt( navigator.getItemIndex( myView ) )`;
And then shutting down the camera, and ultimately removing all handles to the myView, and setting it to null, to have the GC pick it up..

Beware syntax may be different when you wish to remove the item. I never used the navigator..

Comment: yes, i tried that. the navigator has a own syntax for it and it is possible to clear the navigator ( imagine the navigator works as a stack which stores all views so you can allways go back). but clearing it (which is the same as removeItemAt) just causes the stack to be empty but the views are still present and active.

Comment: The rest of my explanation after removeItemAt, was to indicate, that after you remove it from the navigator, take the removed instance ( removeItemAt will return it to you ) and call your own methods for shutting down the view, and releasing any evenlisteners held by the view/ any eventlisteners listening for the view. Then, GC can pick it up. You could end the proc. by doing a item = null...